# How to share the Remember me cookie between Spring Apps in the same domain?

Tags: java, spring, authentication, cookies, spring-security

I'm developing an environment with 2 webapps deployed in Tomcat 7. One authenticate users using form, openid, remember me cookie or x509 cert. This one works as expected and use the Remember me cookie to authenticate properly when generated.

The problem resides in the second one (the client):

When the login request comes back to the client from the first one, I don't see any cookie. I'm pretty sure they are in the same domain (localhost) and the cookie path is "/" but the browser (firefox) is not sending the cookie to the client.

If I want to use the generated remember me cookie  to authenticate in the client, do I need to include all remember me cookie stuff from Spring's security?

Is the remember me cookie a good approach? Do I need something like siteminder or other better approaches?

Thanks in advance. Answers will be voted

Answer (score 0):

Check the cookie information when it is sent back from the server (use Firebug to monitor the network traffic if you're using Firefox).

Check the domain and path, and also whether the cookie is flagged as secure. If the remember-me cookie is issued over a secure connection it will be marked as secure and the browser won't send it over HTTP.

If this is the case, you have to explicitly override it (though you're better to use HTTPS throughout). There's a `use-secure-cookie` attribute in the `remember-me` namespace element which you can set.